# Error from save causing HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I for some reason can't wrap my mind around what I am doing wrong. The error comes when I save a project. What do I need to change?

**ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection occurred in user_boards#show:**

**Cannot modify association 'Project#todos' because the source reflection class 'Todo' is associated to 'List' via :has_many.**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todos, through: :lists
  has_many :labels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_lists, -> { where('status = "active"').order(position: :asc) }, :class_name => 'TodoList', dependent: :destroy


class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  acts_as_list scope: :list, add_new_at: :top
  has_one :project, through: :list

class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :todos, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_todo_lists, -> { where('status = "active"').order(position: :asc) }, :class_name => 'TodoList'
  has_many :active_todos, -> { where('status = "active"').order(position: :asc) }, :class_name => 'Todo'
  acts_as_list scope: :project
```

Comment: The associations are conflicting with each other. I don't think you need to link both project and todo through list - just one of them.

Comment: what two associations are conflicting? I'll see if I can remove the has_one :project on the class Todo.

Comment: Do you need `has_one :project, through: :list`? If ToDo already has an association to List, and List has an association to Project?

Comment: If you remove that, then you have to type todo.list.project everytime instead of just todo.project.